# Relation between entropy of variable and entropy of conditioned variable

Tags: information-theory

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, and let $E$ be an event on the same probability space as $X$. Let $X_E$ be $X$ *conditioned* on the event $E$. Is there a general relationship between the Shannon entropy of $X$ and $X_E$?

I originally thought that one could say that $H(X_E) \geq H(X) - \log 1/\Pr(E)$, but this is not true: consider a $p$-biased coin $X$, and let $E$ denote the event that $X$ lands ``heads'' (which happens with probability $p$). Then, $H(X_E) = 0$, but $H(X) - \log 1/\Pr(E) = p\log(1/p) + (1 - p)\log(1/(1-p)) - \log(1/p) = (1 - p)\log p/(1 -p) > 0$, when $p > 1/2$.

Is there nothing we can say about the two quantities?

Comment: In general, conditioning could reduce Entropy. $$H(X)\geq H(X|A)$$ where $A$ is an event. To see this, the Mutual Information definition is as follows. $$I(X;A)=H(X)-H(X|A)$$. Mutual Information is non-negative and hence the result follows.

Comment: Hi Sudarsan: that is correct, but here I'm talking about the entropy of $X|A = 1$, rather than the conditional entropy of $X|A$, which is the convex combination of the entropies of $X|A = a$.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is though. Conditioning on an event in the same probability space only induces a random variable with a reduced sample space whose Entropy is less than or equal to the Entropy of the original random variable. $X_E$ is also a random variable and in your example, once you condition that the coin takes a value 'heads', the random variable becomes degenerate.

Comment: Sudarsan, here's an example where $H(X_E)$ can be much greater than $H(X)$. Consider the following experiment: flip a coin $E$ that is heads with probability $0.01$. If $E$ is tails, then $X = 0$. If $E$ is heads, then $X$ is a fair coin. Thus, $H(X)$ is close to $0$, yet $H(X_{E = 1}) = 1$.

Comment: I understand your argument now. From your example your definition of the random variable X is as follows: X is 0 with probability .99 and X is 'I'm a fair coin' with probability 0.01. When the event heads occurs X becomes degenerate and it takes on just one value i.e. 'I'm a fair coin' whose entropy is 0.

Comment: To broadly answer your question now that I understand the notion, your last example takes X to a completely different sample space defined by a Bernoulli with probability one half. Hence this particular comparison looks like you want to compare the entropies of two different sample spaces with two different probability measures. Hence there is no relation between them I.e. it is like asking if you can arbitrarily compare the entropies of two different probability spaces.

Comment: I agree with @Sudarsan's last comment. No relation.

Comment: The two distributions cannot be completely unrelated. For example, we have the following relationship: $H(X_E) \geq H_{\mathrm{min}}(X_E) \geq H_{\mathrm{min}}(X) - \log(1/\Pr(E))$, where $H_{\mathrm{min}}(\cdot)$ is the min-entropy of a random variable.

Comment: What are $H_{min}(X_E)$ and $H_{min}(X)$ in the above inequality?

Comment: $H_{\mathrm{min}}(X) = \min_{x} \log 1/\Pr(X = x)$. An operational interpretation of this quantity is: "how well can you guess this random variable correctly?".